# Redirect to webview activity in android

Tags: android, redirect, webview, fatal-error

so i am trying to launch WebView activity from main activity upon successful log-in. the main activity looks like :

```
              try {

                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://192.168.1.101/adddrop/login.php", postParameters);

                Log.v(LOG_TAG," PostParameters = " +postParameters.toString());

                 String res=response.toString();
                 res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");

                 Log.v(LOG_TAG," response value = " +res);


                if(res.equals("1")){

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Registration.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);

                    //error.setText("Correct Username or Password");
                }
                else
                    error.setText("Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                USER.setText(e.toString());
            }
```

and the another activity WebView (Edit :Which is called Registration.java which works fine when i launch it as main activity in a separate project) looks like this :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.101/adddrop/index2.php");
    mWebView.setInitialScale(130);


}

private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and here is the logcat upon clicking log-in where i get successful response with debigging but it's supposed to take me to the web page but else the application crashes and closes :

```
05-19 12:02:39.394: W/dalvikvm(433): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-18 11:24:22.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1094): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 11:24:22.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1094): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.login/com.example.login.Registration}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-18 11:24:22.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-18 11:24:22.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-18 11:24:22.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-18 11:24:22.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-18 11:24:22.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-18 11:24:22.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-18 11:24:22.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-18 11:24:22.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-18 11:24:22.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-18 11:24:22.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-18 11:24:22.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-18 11:24:22.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-18 11:24:22.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1094): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-18 11:24:22.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at com.example.login.Registration.onCreate(Registration.java:19)
05-18 11:24:22.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-18 11:24:22.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-18 11:24:22.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Registration seems to be null

Comment: Registration.java see line ...19

Comment: Deleting my answer, @SamirMangroliya got it in a comment before I finished typing.

Comment: You should just make a webapp.  Activities that are big webviews shouldn't even be allowed on the play store.  This is the one [and probably only] case where I would argue for an App review process (such as Apple's).

Comment: @SamirMangroliya Line 19 contains this :    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); i have deleted it since my webpage does not contain javascript , now the logcat gives me error at line 20 , i even tried to move the loadUrl line upwards it gives me error at it.

Comment: Are you sure you have a <WebView> in the "main.xml" with id="@+id/webview"? Go to main.xml and check if it is there with this id

Comment: @SherifelKhatib i have two files in the layout folder one main.xml corresponding to the main activity and another webview.xml corresponding to the other activity Registraion.java, this contains the declaration you mentioned. Is this right ?

Comment: @Jawad no this is not right! at all! Use my answer to open a webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webview activity should be something like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    WebView mWebView = new WebView(this);

    //now do whatever you want
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.101/adddrop/index2.php");
    mWebView.setInitialScale(130);

    //finally
    setContentView(mWebView);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you added your activity in the manifest file? Like this:

```
<activity 
        android:name="your.package.name.Registration"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

**UPDATE**

I think you need to exchange the order of two lines.

From:

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.101/adddrop/index2.php");
mWebView.setInitialScale(130);
```

To:

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.101/adddrop/index2.php");
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
mWebView.setInitialScale(130);
```

And don't forget to add Internet permission on your manifest...

```
<manifest ... >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
...
</manifest>
```

**UPDATE 2**

Change this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Registration.class);
```

to:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, Registration.class);
```

Comment: I have tried this, the logcat gives me error at line 20 which contains
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.101/adddrop/index2.php");
note that this registration.java class works completely fine when i launch it alone as main activity in a separate project...